# Time-series plot: change x-axis format in R

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I'm trying to change the x-axis labels on a ts plot from the default (e.g. year.samplenumber) to an actual date. I had already searched in other threads, but the solution I found isn't quite working for me.

```
mm17

   date fullband band1 
1 2015/1/14 109.0873 107.0733     
2 2015/1/15 110.1434 109.1999     
3 2015/1/16 109.8811 108.6232     
4 2015/1/17 110.4814 109.8164     
5 2015/1/18 110.1513 109.2764     
6 2015/1/19 110.3266 109.5860     

mm17.ts<-ts(mm17.perday[,2], frequency=365, start=c(2015, 14))

cols<-c("red", "green", "orange", "purble", "blue")
dates<-as.Date(mm17[,1])

ts.plot(mm17.ts, col=cols[1], xaxt="n")
axis(1, dates, format(dates, "%m %d"), cex.axis = .7)
```

[image: TS Plot]

As you can see the axis command isn't working for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, ts class is not a good fit for daily data.  It is more suitable for monthly, quarterly and annual data.

For daily data, it would be easier to just convert it to zoo and plot:

```
library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo(mm17, format = "%Y/%m/%d")
plot(z$fullband, col = "red")
```

[image: screenshot]

### Note

We assume the `mm17` is given as shown below.

```
Lines <- "   date fullband band1 
1 2015/1/14 109.0873 107.0733     
2 2015/1/15 110.1434 109.1999     
3 2015/1/16 109.8811 108.6232     
4 2015/1/17 110.4814 109.8164     
5 2015/1/18 110.1513 109.2764     
6 2015/1/19 110.3266 109.5860"
mm17 <- read.table(text = Lines)
```

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly! Though,is there a way to change the format of the x-axis labels?

Also, can I extend this to hours? I have another dataset with hours of day (i.e. 0-23). On a first try, it wasn't working, but I'm not familiar with time-series, yet

Comment: The axis command can be used.   If there are times and no dates look at the chron package's "times" class.  If you have dates and times you can use POSIXct or chron.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening here is a mismatch between the underlying numeric values of the dates as plotted by `ts.plot` and the `dates` vector. The x-axis dates in the output of `ts.plot` literally have magnitudes of 2015.1, 2015.2 etc. However, the underlying numeric values of the dates in the `dates` vector are the number of days from January 1, 1970 to the given date (dates in R are actually numeric values with a `Date` class attached). For example:

```
dates
```

> ```
> [1] "2015-01-14" "2015-01-15" "2015-01-16" "2015-01-17" "2015-01-18" "2015-01-19"
> ```

```
as.numeric(dates)
```

> ```
> [1] 16449 16450 16451 16452 16453 16454
> ```

```
x=16449
class(x)="Date"
x
```

> ```
> [1] "2015-01-14"
> ```

You can also see this with the following code. We expand the x-axis range to include the numeric values listed above. Note how you can see one of your date labels way out on the right end of the plot at 16,449, while the data values are plotted near the left side at 2015:

```
ts.plot(mm17.ts, col=cols[1], xlim=c(0, 16455))
axis(1, dates, format(dates, "%m %d"), cex.axis = .8, col.axis="red")
axis(1, 2015, 2015, cex.axis = .8, col.axis="red")
```

[image]

So, let's change the `at` argument in the `axis` function so that we get the date labels placed at the correct locations. We'll use a couple of functions from the `lubridate` package to help with this. Also, note that to remove the default x-axis labels, `ts.plot` requires that `xaxt` (and other graphical parameters) be passed as a list using the `gpars` argument (see the `ts.plot` help for more on this):

```
library(lubridate)

ts.plot(mm17.ts, col=cols[1], gpars=list(xaxt="n"))
axis(1, at=year(dates) + yday(dates)/365.24, labels=format(dates, "%m %d"), cex.axis = .7)
```

[image]